# Play WAV file backward

Tags: java, stream, audio

I'm making [Braid](http://www.braid-game.com) in Java. If you rewind the time, the sound plays backward.
How can I play a WAV file backward? Maybe with a stream with something like `previous()`?
On the site of Braid can you see what I mean.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it by myself

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author Martijn
 */
public class FrameBuffer {

    private byte[][] frames;
    private int frameSize;

    public FrameBuffer(AudioInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        readFrames(stream);
    }

    public byte[] getFrame(int i) {
        return frames[i];
    }

    public int numberFrames()
    {
        return frames.length;
    }

    public int frameSize()
    {
        return frameSize;
    }

    private void readFrames(AudioInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        frameSize = stream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
        frames = new byte[stream.available() / frameSize][frameSize];
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < frames.length; i++)
        {
            byte[] frame = new byte[frameSize];
            int numBytes = stream.read(frame, 0, frameSize);
            if (numBytes == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            frames[i] = frame;
        }
        System.out.println("FrameSize = " + frameSize);
        System.out.println("Number frames = " + frames.length);
        System.out.println("Number frames read = " + i);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
 FrameBuffer frameStream = new FrameBuffer(austream); //austream is the audiostream
 int frame = frameStream.numberFrames() - 1;
 while (frame >= 0) {
      auline.write(frameStream.getFrame(frame), 0, frameStream.frameSize());
      frame--;
 }
```

Comment: @Martijn Can you please tell what is auline in this line... " auline.write(frameStream.getFrame(frame), 0, frameStream.frameSize());"

Comment: It is the audiochannel to the sound card. It is a `SourceDataLine` instance. Take a look at this example: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux nice answer. can you tell me difference between  "for(int i = 0; i <frames.length; i++)" and this "int i = 0; for (; i < frames.length; i++)" regarding memory ?

Comment: @chiragsaga: `int i` won't go off the stack when the loop is finished in the second example. That is it. I'm doing it because I want to know how many frames I read. Check out the println.

Answer (score 2):

If the WAV contains PCM, reverse the order of the PCM samples. If it contains some other format it can be a lot more complex; probably easiest to just convert it to PCM first.

For more information on the WAV format, see [this site](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. But I don't know how to do that with the PCM's. Maybe you can write an exemple or a site where I can find some information?

Comment: I added a link to a description of the WAV format; if you're having problems ask specific questions about the parts you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Sound Recorder (in Start --> Programs --> Accessories --> Entertainment).

It has a feature (Effects (menu) --> Reverse) to reverse a .WAV file.  You could save the reversed file with a different name, and then open the appropriate one in your program.

Comment: they're to many soundfiles (+50) to reverse them all. I thought allready ont it, but...