# Reversing audio in Java?

Tags: java, audio

My friends and I are making a game in Java that requires a small [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) to be reversed.

Any thoughts? Either there is a library for this, or the solution will be much, much harder.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267488/play-wav-file-backward

Comment: Don't get into trouble with religious fanatics chasing for backmasked satanic messages, like the Beatles and Zappa did...     :-)

Comment: Hi @Alec Sloman do you find any implementation to reverse audio?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Sound tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html):

> If you're processing incoming sound,
>   you can read the bytes from a
>   TargetDataLine and then manipulate
>   them. An algorithmically trivial
>   example that can yield sonically
>   intriguing results is to play a sound
>   backwards by arranging its frames in
>   reverse order.

I haven't dug deeply enough to figure out how to do this, but if they write about it as an example it's obviously possible.

Comment: Awesome! That's a great start. If anyone out there knows of an implementation, boy would I appreciate a link.

Thanks Carl!