# How to play audio from m4a backwards in swift 4(without creating new files)

Tags: swift

Is this possible? If not I’ll have to accept that this question is a duplicate from one that the answer results in an aiff file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse an audio file Swift/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310944/reverse-an-audio-file-swift-objective-c)

Comment: I guess it is kinda but...Is the explanation in that question still true? Is it possible to buffer the audio somehow instead of create a new file? And who uses aiff files? I need it to work in m4a.