# How to play an .mp3 file reversely in java

Tags: java, audio-streaming, binaryfiles

I want to develop an android application **in which the user can play an .mp3 song file reversely ( playing backwards)**. 
I have searched a lot on the web and the stackoverflow, but I haven't found anything useful and **basically I'm short on the main idea behind this scenario.** 
So I'd like to know if there are any java libraries for manipulating .mp3 files or sample applications. Any insight is appreciated :)

Comment: The only way to do this is to decode to PCM samples first.  MP3 only decodes one direction.

Comment: And what I should I after decoding the file to PCM samples ?

Comment: Once you have PCM samples, you can play them in any direction or any way you want.

Comment: Thanks Brad . I'll work on these and will update the question asap ☺

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to convert it to WAV (on the fly) and then play it using the following answer:

[Play WAV file backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267488/play-wav-file-backward)